# Full list of the API methods for iTunes's COM interface?

Tags: api, com, itunes

I'm looking around, but I can't seem to find documentation for iTunes's COM interface anywhere.  The best I've found are isolated code fragments and method calls.

Does anyone know where I can find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "iTunes COM for Windows SDK" at [connect.apple.com](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/login). I remember iterating through all of the available methods with some gnarly `VBScript` many years ago, but that wasn't documentation...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Qt, you can get the documentation with the following snippet:

```
QFile file(filename);
QAxObject * object =new QAxObject("iTunes.Application", this);
if (object && file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
  QTextStream out(&file);
  QString doc = object->generateDocumentation();
  out<<doc;
}
```

The generated file is an HTML file listing available properties, signals, slots and code snippets to use them.